# "I'd never wished to" or "I've never wished to"?

Tags: tense, past-tense

I was trying to say I wish I would not be like what I look like now (I mean not  in terms of appearance but actually attitude), but I was not sure how to gather the grammar that would fit together correctly.

Here is the dialogue:

> person A: I'm a web user.
>
> person B: Great.
>
> person A: not sure if it's great.
>
> person B: why?
>
> person A: I'd never wished to.
>
> person B: you have to say, I've never wished to.

So, which one is correct, "I'd never wished to" or "I've never wished to"? and why?

Besides, I wanted to know what I am wrong about and what specific thing I should pay more attention to, while I'm speaking or maybe writing.

Comment: Besides the issue of tense, which has been addressed well, the answer doesn't quite match the dialogue.  Wished to _do what_?  ‘Web user’ isn't a verb.  The meaning is clear, and in colloquial English it'd be fine, but if you wanted to be strictly correct I think you'd probably have to say something like “I never wished to _be_.” or “I never wished to _be one_.”  (And in colloquial English I think you'd be more likely to say “wanted” rather than “wished”, though the distinction is rather fine.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a reason for the different tenses in English, they relate to different times and the relationship between times.

> I've never wished to.

This means that you have never wished to in your whole life, right up to this conversation with person B.

> I'd never wished to

This means that there was a time in the past, before which you hadn't wished to.

Example

Until my last birthday, I had never wished to be a web user, but then someone gave me a laptop and now I am addicted to it.

Answer (score 3):

It's about the fact that *"I **'d** never wished to be"* has a stronger stress on the word compared to *"I **'ve** never wished to be"* That's why I think the former, to a degree, more emphatically refers to the past. In this context, both are perfectly correct and can be used interchangeably. I doubt native speakers would hesitate to say either.

@gidds Colloquial English: *I never wanted to be [one].*

Now, to answer this question!

> What specific thing should I pay more attention to, while I'm speaking
> or maybe writing?

When you speak or write, you will have to focus on using a wide range of different  sentence syntax and think of how you can organize words idiomatically and also make sure you use as many common expressions as possible - by doing so, you'll be able to recognize incorrect ones. It's essential for your success in English.

You should avoid odd constructions and word combinations like: "we don't do a mistake" - "we *make* a mistake." Finally, you should almost never drop articles or try to skip them. Everything I said is important and it will lead to speaking and writing authentic, native-sounding English. But also keep in mind that I haven't covered everything and you should look for some resources online - I believe there are a lot of guidelines and articles.

The more you read, listen to and speak English, the better you'll get at it.